# inheriting from shared_ptr<void>

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm inheriting from `shared_ptr<void>` to store an extra filed `length` that shows the length of memory allocated by `malloc` function.
I'm also passing `free` as a custom delete function.

```
// a chunk of memory that will automatically be deleted
struct bytes : public std::shared_ptr<void> {
public:
   unsigned int length;
   bytes(std::nullptr_t) :
       std::shared_ptr<void>(nullptr),
       length(0) { }
   bytes(int len) :
       std::shared_ptr<void>(malloc(len), free),
       length(len) { }
};

// a sample use case
bytes foo(int n){
   if( condition1)
      return nullptr;
   bytes b(100);
   // ....
   fread(b.get(),1,100,file_pointer);
   // ....
   return b;
}
```

I'm just not sure if this code has hidden bugs or not ? (I'm new to c++11).

Comment: wait i will just update the question ...

Comment: @Puppy Premature ej- post sorry :) ...

Comment: i don't know why my last sentence was not copied correctly.

Comment: @amin Why are you using `malloc`? Also in general the standard library classes are rarely designed to inherit from them.

Comment: i want to allocate a chunk of memory.

Comment: i know that in c++ i should use new char[] instead

Comment: `shared_ptr` has a non-virtual destructor. Inheriting it is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: @amin: Don't ever use `new T[]`. Ever.

Comment: @erenon i used a custom custom function for `my_free` instead of `free` and it called correctly . are you sure that the shared_ptr destructor is virtual ?

Comment: @amin: it is non virtual, that's the point.

Comment: @amin: It's undefined behaviour, regardless of whether or not `free` actually gets called.

Comment: @Puppy but if the constructor is virtual. then it can not be undefined behavior(right?)

Comment: @amin _"but if the constructor is virtual"_ There's no such thing.

Comment: @amin That doesn't make sense. A constructor can never be virtual. Did you mean destructor? If the destructor were virtual, then deleting through a pointer-to-base would be valid, but as noted, the destructor isn't virtual, and nothing in your own class can change that.

Comment: you may have better luck at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry i mean `destructor is virtual` .

Comment: @hvd thank you. then this code is a mess and has hidden bugs.

Comment: @hvd @Puppy  `shared_ptr<void>* p = new bytes(100); delete p;` is this the only type of undefined behavior this code has ?

Comment: No, another problem is that `malloc` returns `NULL` on failure, it doesn't throw, and you happily pass that on to `fread`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a truly terrible idea. It's just `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>>`, but with added awful like inheriting from a class with a non-virtual destructor.

You should really favour composing existing Standard classes rather than crapping around on your own. It is vastly superior.

Comment: or even just `std::vector<char>`. I don't think he really needs the `shared_ptr`; he just needs auto delete.

Comment: @tenfour `std::vector<char>` gets copied when the function returns (right?)

Comment: To add to @tenfour's comment, return-value optimisation is not required, and the exact situations where compilers perform RVO depend on the compiler. However, even when RVO is not working, returning a local variable or an rvalue will use a move, not a copy, which leaves the pointed-to memory exactly as it is.